# Difference between available UWP menu controls

Tags: c#, menu, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am new to UWP and would like to know what the difference is between “Flyout”, “ContextFlyout” and “Popup”. Also, I would like to know the difference between “AppBar” and “CommandBar”. I believe these are containers to hold menus or menu items. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Problem: I am trying design the UI of an app and want to know how to best display menu items and menus and would like to know the difference between these so I can pick the one that works best for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: The docs discuss when to use which at length: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/app-bars , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/menus , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs

Comment: The UWP Community Toolkit also has a [Menu Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/Menu).

Comment: You should use a `CommandBar` instead of an `AppBar`.  AppBar is for compatibility with Win8 apps, CommandBar is its replacement, as per doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/app-bars).

Answer (score 3):

ContextFlyout is designed for the "right-click menu" operation. For example, this menu is automatically assigned for the inputs as following. If you want to implement the context menu, ContextFlyout is the best.

- Mouse - Right click
- Touch - Tap and hold
- Xbox Controller - Menu button

Popup / Flyout is generic one, it can be used for any popup/flyout UI, not only for the menus. And, there are no default event handling like as context flyout. You need to assign the righttapped or something to invoke the popup/flyout.